# Cannot get hidden GRUB2 menu to appear?

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, menu

I have a dual boot (Ubuntu/Ubuntu) system and have configured GRUB2 to hide the boot menu unless I press the shift key (or another key).  Here is my configuration in /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=3
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

However, no matter what I do, or what key I press, or when I press it, it boots up into the default OS choice and I never see the GRUB menu.  I always do a `sudo update-grub` after changing these options.

I've tried extending the hidden timeout to 15 seconds and my system didn't change...its like that value is just not being honored -- the system just boots up right away.

I do have a software RAID 1 configuration, but each drive is mirrored and they both have Grub, so that can't be it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Change GRUB_TIMEOUT to some value e.g 10, update grub and your problem will be solved. Reboot and Press the Shift key.

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=3
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

refer to [Grub2 Files and Options](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275)

If this didn't work for you then there is another way to do this which involves changing the `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` file. After backing up the file I did the following steps and it worked fine for me.

So, open terminal and write

```
sudo gedit /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober
```

A file will open. Change the following Code:

```
make_timeout () {
  if [ "x${found_other_os}" = "x" ] ; then
    if [ "x${1}" != "x" ] ; then
      if [ "x${GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET}" = "xtrue" ] ; then
    verbose=
      else
    verbose=" --verbose"
      fi

      if [ "x${1}" = "x0" ] ; then
    cat <<EOF
if [ "x\${timeout}" != "x-1" ]; then
  if keystatus; then
    if keystatus --shift; then
      set timeout=-1
    else
      set timeout=0
    fi
  else
    if sleep$verbose --interruptible 3 ; then
      set timeout=0
    fi
  fi
fi
EOF
      else
    cat << EOF
if [ "x\${timeout}" != "x-1" ]; then
  if sleep$verbose --interruptible ${GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT} ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
EOF
      fi
    fi
  fi
}

adjust_timeout () {
  if [ "x$GRUB_BUTTON_CMOS_ADDRESS" != "x" ]; then
    cat <<EOF
if cmostest $GRUB_BUTTON_CMOS_ADDRESS ; then
EOF
    make_timeout "${GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_BUTTON}" "${GRUB_TIMEOUT_BUTTON}"
    echo else
    make_timeout "${GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT}" "${GRUB_TIMEOUT}"
    echo fi
  else
    make_timeout "${GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT}" "${GRUB_TIMEOUT}"
  fi
}
```

Into this:

```
adjust_timeout () {
        cat <<EOF
        if keystatus --shift; then
          set timeout=-1
        else
          set timeout=0
        fi
EOF
}
```

And save the file.

After running `sudo update-grub` shutdown the system.

Now when you start your system again, you'll have to **press and hold** the shift key **immediately** after pressing the power button. This will lead you to Grub. If you do not press the shift key, you will be booted into your default operating system automatically.
Best of luck!

**Note**: If anything goes wrong or some unexpected behavior occurs, change the code back to original using the backup file and everything will be back to normal again.

Comment: Doing that just enabled the normal GRUB menu with the countdown specified in GRUB_TIMEOUT.  However, I'd like to not see the GRUB menu unless I press a key.

Comment: You are right. It should work but because of some reason it neither worked for me. But I have found an alternate method to achieve that. I have improved the answer. Follow the steps and see if it works.

Comment: @HDave did you get the desired results?